# Why doesn't my App Chooser dialogue show?

Tags: android

I am using [this tutorial to](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) learn about the basics of Intents in Android. The code sample I am using is adopted from the section named "Force an App Chooser" on the page linked.

The following is the method which should be invoked on the click of the button.

```
public void startSecondActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String fileChooserLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.fileChooserLabel); 

        Intent fileChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, fileChooserLabel);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) { 
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view); 
            textView.setText("False");
        }
```

}

**But it just enters the `else` block of the `if-else` conditional. I tried this app on both a real device and the emulator. So can anybody point out what might be wrong here, and what I can do about it.**

Note: I did not add anything to the Manifest file, since I am using Eclipse IDE and I suppose whatever is required at this point is automatically added to the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning `null` because there are no activities on the device that support your `Intent`. In this case, your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` is not properly set up.

Note that the code sample you used as a reference is not a tutorial. It is not designed to be a complete code sample. In fact, what they list there will not even compile, as their `...` is meant to be replaced by your own code to complete setting up the `Intent`.

You will need to fully configure your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, most notably setting the MIME type, as is covered elsewhere in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). Replacing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

with something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                      .setType("text/plain")
                      .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "IM IN UR STAK OVERFLO ANZWR");
```

should suffice.